# Help with Divi logo not appearing for 10s

Tags: themes, css

OK, this is a weird one.  For reference, I've dug into CSS issues, and JavaScript issues, and I can't seem to find why this is happening.

When you first go to the [staging site](https://milkiostaging.wpengine.com?nocache), part of the secondary menu appears:
[image: screenshot1]

After about 10s, the remainder of the header appears:
[image: screenshot2]

I'm thinking it is NOT something Divi related since the secondary menu is partially showing.  However, it could be some simple setting in Divi I'm unfamiliar with.

I'm suspecting there's a CSS animation somewhere, as you can see from the Animations section of the performance tab below:
[image: performance tab]

Anybody have any insights or suggestions as to what else I could try?

Comment: This is a pure JS problem with the JS code you  linked to, that should have been asked on  stackoverflow. You used  `setTimeout` to trigger  events and passed in  long delays, hence the long delay. Just  run your JS on the document ready hook instead of trying to time things. If you need to delay the appearance of an element, use a CSS animation/transition instead of javascript

Comment: @TomJNowell, I realized my question was misleading, and I cleaned it up.  I removed the debugging code references that were confusing.  I had added that code trying to determine what was happening in the first 10s of the site load

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, I still think that solving and understanding this will need only CSS or JS knowledge though, so you're limiting your options by asking in WP circles, unless it's a Divi problem, in which case the Divi community are better placed to answer that. Stack Exchange isn't so great for diagnosing issues rather fixing issues once they're identified